# Как преобразовать текст формулы из одной ячейки в действующую формулу в другой ячейке google spreadsheets

Tags: таблицы, скрипт, формулы, google-spreadsheet

В таблице функции обрабатывают импортируемые данные и формируют новую функцию в текстовом формате. Исходные данные и функция меняются.
Прошу помощи. Какой скрипт после активации скопирует текст формулы (есть вариант с "=", а есть без "=") из ячейки A1 листа "Формула" и заменит имеющуюся формулу в ячейке A1 листа "Действие"
Далее новая формула должна выполниться на листе "Действие"

Надоело копировать и вставлять, хочу автоматизировать процесс по изменению листа "Формула" таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Здесь значения диапазона `A1:A2` с листа 'Формула' вставляются в виде формул в диапазон `A1:A2` на листе 'Действие'. Формулы сразу вычисляются. Диапазон можно менять.

```
function setValuesAsFormulas(){
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  book.getSheetByName('Действие').getRange('A1:A2').setFormulas(book.getSheetByName('Формула').getRange('A1:A2').getValues())
}
```